# "potentially dangerous Request.Path value" caused by ampersand (that shouldn't be there)

Tags: asp.net

I am working on an ASP.NET website. The website's users are sent an email with a link to the site. The link will look something like this:

```
https://<website>/Default.aspx?LC=<guid>
```

where the "LC" parameter is their login code. The "LC" parameter is the *only* parameter we ever put on the link. It's also possible to go directly to the Default.aspx page without a code and type one in at the prompt.

Here's the problem: on rare occasions (but consistently since the site launched), I've been getting an error report from the Global.asax handler that says:

```
12:24:41 ERROR Global.asax - Application_Error - unhandled error: 
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)
```

I have no idea why I keep getting these messages. I've tried logging HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl to see the actual URL the client is using, but all I ever get is this:

```
/&
```

and HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath reports as:

```
~/&
```

Is there some way I can log the "real" request and see where this ampersand is coming from? The LC parameter value is always a GUID so it would never have an ampersand in it. Also, this problem does not seem to happen for 99% of the site users. For all I know this is being caused by a bot or something, but if it's happening to real users I'd like to find out why.

Comment: What makes you think this is not the real request?

Comment: Good question. :-) I really don't have an answer for that. But one thing I didn't mention is that this is a survey website, and the survey has about 7 "pages". Whenever this problem happens I actually get 7 error reports (usually 30 seconds to a minute apart) for the same session Id, so it seems like the person is going through the survey pages and each page is somehow sending this errant request. But since it's so rare I don't know what to make of it. I'm really just looking for some way to debug this so I can fix the issue, but I can't reproduce it.

Comment: Do you log the URL referrer?

Comment: Yes, but it just shows the name of the page. It doesn't show any additional parameters.

Comment: Maybe some broken browser extension does this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "broken" but it could be a browser extension. I did wonder if there might be some particular device that causes this, but when I log the UserAgent string for the browser I see a  bunch of different ones.